# How to mock boost throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, googletest, googlemock

I have code which interacts with the filesystem using `boost` which looks like:

```
FileMigrater::migrate() const {
    //stuff
    try {
        boost::filesystem::create_direcotry(some_path_);
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Bad stuff happened";
        return MigrationResult::Failed;
    }
    //more stuff
}
```

I'm using `gmock` and `gtest` to write unit tests for the `migrate` method and I'd like to write a test for the case where `boost` throws an exception. Ideally, I'd like to write a unit test which looks something like (the syntax of this will be wrong because I'm new c++ in general):

```
TEST_F(MyTest, boost_exception_test) {
    ON_CALL(boost_mock, create_directory()).Throw(std::exception);

    EXPECT_EQ(Migration::Failed, migrater.migrate());
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create the `boost_mock` or even if that's the right approach to the problem.

Comment: My approach: Silently sit there and have your avatar facepalm whenever boost throws one such exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testing approach is quite good. The point is that [googlemock](/questions/tagged/googlemock) cannot mock free functions and `boost::filesystem::create_directory()` is one.

However, the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions) suggests an approach to work around it:

> It's possible to use Google Mock to mock a free function (i.e. a
>   C-style function or a static method). You just need to rewrite your
>   code to use an interface (abstract class).
>
> Instead of calling a free function (say, OpenFile) directly, introduce
>   an interface for it and have a concrete subclass that calls the free
>   function:
>
> ```
> class FileInterface {
> public:
>  ...
>  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) = 0;
> };
> class File : public FileInterface {
> public:
>  ...
>  virtual bool Open(const char* path, const char* mode) {
>   return OpenFile(path, mode);
>  }
> };
> ```
>
> Your code should talk to FileInterface to open a file. Now it's easy to mock out the function.
>
> This may seem much hassle, but in practice you often have multiple
>   related functions that you can put in the same interface, so the
>   per-function syntactic overhead will be much lower.
>
> If you are concerned about the performance overhead incurred by
>   virtual functions, and profiling confirms your concern, you can
>   combine this with the recipe for [mocking non-virtual methods](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods).

Comment: my `FileMigrater` class should then take in a `FileInterface` as a dependency in the constructor, right?

Comment: Yes, you must inject the dependency someway. Using the constructor is a common one. You could also have a static member in `FileMigrater` if you don't want to keep a reference for each instance and you can share the same `FileInterface` object.